# Java - subtract paused time from playtime

Tags: java, time

I have two instance variables:
`private Instant elapsedTime;` and `private Instant pauseTime;`

Then I have a method which calculates the playtime based on the elapsed time and the paused time, but it's not doing it correctly.
My current code is:

```
public void pausePlay(boolean paused) {
        // If elapsed time isn't already made, make it
        if (elapsedTime == null) {
            elapsedTime = Instant.now();
        }
        if (paused) {
            pauseTime = Instant.now();
        } else {
            if (pauseTime != null) {
                elapsedTime = elapsedTime.plusMillis(Duration.between(elapsedTime, pauseTime).toMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I pause the program, it works just fine. But the problem which the next pauses is that the playtime doesn't count from where it was at **before** the program got paused, but it goes back to before the program got paused the first time.

I already tried setting the pauseTime to null anywhere in the method, but it didn't work.

Are there any fixes for this?

================================

Edit: I fixed it by changing the following code...

```
elapsedTime = elapsedTime.plusMillis(Duration.between(elapsedTime, pauseTime).toMillis());
```

...into this:

```
long pausedTime = Duration.between(pauseTime, Instant.now()).toMillis();
elapsedTime = elapsedTime.plusMillis(pausedTime);
```

Comment: Playtime is the same as elapsedTime. When the game is paused, that's when pauseTime is activated with elapsedTime still running, and when it gets unpaused,, pauseTime needs to get substracted from elapsedTime.

Comment: Your logic escapes me. What exactly is your goal? Are you trying to accumulate elapsed time in each mode, how much time elapsed while paused and how much time in play mode? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: How hard is it to understand this? I'm trying to subtract the paused time from the elapsed time, so the game doesn't count time the time when it got paused.

Answer (score 0):

### The Duration class for an amount of elapsed time

It’s not perfectly clear to me, but I seem to understand that you want to keep track of elapsed time and how much of it has been paused time. I think it takes a bit more than your code, but not bad. The following class sees playing time and paused time as pretty symmetrical and keeps track of each separately. Maybe you can adjust it to your needs.

Use the `Duration` class for an amount of time, for example how much time has been spent in paused and in non-paused modes.

```
public class Game {

    // At most one of playTime and pauseTime is non-null
    // and signifies the game is either playing or paused since that instant.
    Instant playTime = null;
    Instant pauseTime = null;
    
    /** Not including pause time */
    Duration totalPlayTime = Duration.ZERO;
    Duration totalPauseTime = Duration.ZERO;

    /**
     * Records elapsed time.
     * Sets state to either paused or playing controlled by the argument.
     */
    public void pausePlay(boolean paused) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        
        // Add elapsed time since last call to either play time or pause time
        if (playTime != null) {
            totalPlayTime = totalPlayTime.plus(Duration.between(playTime, now));
        } else if (pauseTime != null) {
            totalPauseTime = totalPauseTime.plus(Duration.between(pauseTime, now));
        }
        
        if (paused) {
            playTime = null;
            pauseTime = now;
        } else {
            playTime = now;
            pauseTime = null;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried it out first but then I realized I made the wrong calculation from the start, now it's been fixed with much less code.